# Trying to load scraper itemloader settings from json file

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have built a scrapy parser that works and i'm loading the settings from a json file to set xPaths for scraping and other settings.

```html
{
  "urlEntry": "https://www.realcommercial.com.au/for-sale/",
  "urlDomain": ".*realcommercial.com.au/for-sale/.*",
  "urlScrape": ".*?\\d{9}",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "xPath": "//span[contains(@class, \"propertyId\")]/text()",
      "filter": "\\d{9}"
    },
    ...
```

There are a bunch of bindings. I'm loading the settings file into the spider successfully like this

```js
self.settings = json.load(open("./Scrapy_Agent/config/" + self.name + ".json"))
```

I will worry about the hardcoded part of the path later, the config files are based off the spider name though.

But where I run into trouble is that I have a pipeline that wants to use the filter field from the config file.

I have an ItemLoader that looks like this

```js
class ListingLoader(ItemLoader):

    PostcodeName_out = OutputRegexProcessor("PostcodeName")
    ID_out = OutputRegexProcessor("ID")
    AddressName_out = OutputRegexProcessor("AddressName")
```

and Output RegexProcessor's init looks like this

```js
class OutputRegexProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        settings = json.load(open("./Scrapy_Agent/config/realcommercialsale.json"))
        self.regex = ""
        for binding in settings["bindings"]:
             if (binding["name"] == name):
                 if (binding.get("filter")):
                    self.regex = binding["filter"]
```

The name of the spider is realcommercialsale and this is currently hardcoded here. I'm a bit of a python beginner and i'm stuck trying to find a way to get the name of the current spider down to this point.

I'm not committed to any particular solution to the problem. I need to get the regex string for the item field down in the OutputRegexProcessor. Whether I access the name of the spider and reparse the json file like i'm currently doing, or otherwise pass the json file down somehow, or some other solution I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually worked out a solution to the problem.

Instead of trying to load the file in init, which seems to be a total non-starter, I ended up reading in the config on the first call to the OutputRegexProcessor by adding the filename I needed to the loader_context.

The init sets the data field to None to indicate it isn't loaded yet (with empty string indicating it was loaded but not used) and then the first call checks if it is None. If it is None then it tried to load the data and if it isn't None just runs the already loaded regex.

It worked nicely and I have a generic scraper now that is easily configured from a json file